# WCFM import products using integromat

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, marketplace, make.com

I am trying to create a workflow that builds a catalogue of products for a vendor to fulfill. The vendor will select one of many types of catalog and upon selection the catalogue will be pushed to their store. I am using the Integromat product importer module to pull the data from Airtable successfully imported products in this way. However, I have been unable to assign the products to any vendors. I have tried mapping the user id of vendors to the meta fields listed below - the values are indeed mapped to the fields but the products are not assigned to the vendor.

The meta keys I've tried:

- store,
- vendor,
- _wcfm_product_author,
- product_author,
- seller,
- author,
- store_id,
- vendor_id,
- author_id,
- post_author_id,
- post_author,
- user_id,
- id,
- store_name,
- sold_by,

None of these meta field keys assign an imported product to an author – if you like, I can create a short video showing the process and the outcome if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that WC does not natively support authors - attempts to assign a value to the field 'post_author' creates a meta field which is saved in wp_postmeta instead of wp_post. I found a plugin that adds product author support (allows access to the post_author in wp_post) here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-change-product-author/.

I then used the Wordpress module in Integromat to update my products with the specific authors.